# VBS logical operators initialise empty variables?

Tags: vbscript

Consider the following bit of VBS:

```
dim msg, myVar, myVar2

msg = "myVar = " & myVar
msg = msg & vbcrlf & "myVar = empty: " & isempty(myVar)
msg = msg & vbcrlf & "TypeName(myVar) = " & TypeName(myVar)

msgbox msg, , "BEFORE"

if not myVar then myVar2 = true

msg = "myVar = " & myVar
msg = msg & vbcrlf & "myVar = empty: " & isempty(myVar)
msg = msg & vbcrlf & "TypeName(myVar) = " & TypeName(myVar)

msgbox msg, , "AFTER"
```

I would expect the output from "BEFORE" and "AFTER" to be the same... all we're doing is making a comparison to an uninitialised (empty) variant right?

However - it seems like the "if not" actually initialises it to a (long)zero!
I've been coding in VBS (ASP) for donkey's years, and this is a new one on me!

A few things to note:

- The behaviour is the same in both a .vbs and the equivalent ASP code (on my Win 7 desktop and on Server 2008 R2.)
- All logical operators - and/or/not/xor produce this effect
- Comparison operators do not.

It seems like a potential trap for the unwary... Can anyone explain this behaviour?

Answer (score 6):

I couldn't find anything official about this issue.
After doing some test, I decided that this is a bug or an un-documented effect.
This behaviour does not apply on other similar platforms like VBA and VB6.

**Visual Basic for Application:**

[image: Visual Basic for Application]

**Visual Basic 6:**

[image: Visual Basic 6]

**VBScript:**

[image: VBScript]

As a workaround, passing expressions by value works.

```
If Not (exp) Then
'or
If Not CBool(exp) Then
```

---

[ByRef and ByVal Parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)
[CBool Function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2k9sfx3c%28v=vs.84%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks for testing this in VB6 and VBA too. I agree this looks like a bug. It was a new one on me too, after programming in VBA for about the last 20 years!

Answer (score 5):

If you change that statement in the middle to

```
if not (myVar) then myVar2 = true   'with parenthesis around myVar
```

then you will not witness the same behavior. BEFORE and AFTER are the same now.

That's because apparently the parenthesis force the Not operator to only perform a logical test and will skip the side effect of Not.

On https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/subscriptions/9cy86sfb%28v=vs.84%29.aspx you will find the following about Not

```
In addition, the Not operator inverts the bit values of any variable and
sets the corresponding bit in result according to the following table:
+-------------------+---------------+
| Bit in expression | Bit in result |
+-------------------+---------------+
| 0                 | 1             |
| 1                 | 0             |
+-------------------+---------------+
```

For example

```
Msgbox Not 2   ' is -3
Msgbox Not -3  ' is 2
```

That makes sense if you consider that internally the values are stored as signed bytes/words.

```
000 -4
001 -3  --> 001 inverted is 110
010 -2
011 -1
100  0
101  1
110  2  --> 110 inverted is 001
111  3
```

Let's convert Empty to Long with

```
x = CLng(myVar)
```

You will find that the value of x is 0.

If you use

```
if not myVar then myVar2 = true
```

then the result of not myVar will be evaluated (and the resulting value of -1 will subsequently be thrown away). But the calculation takes place anyhow and for this it is necessary to convert Empty to a long first.

Comment: The difference between `not myVar` and `not (myVar)` is interesting, thanks. Your linked article talks about the value of the result in an assignment statement however - so I'm still looking for an answer on how a non-assignment statement (the `if`) can assign a value!

Comment: `if` doesn't assign the value, `not` does. You could replace your statement with `result = Not myVar` or simply `MsgBox Not myVar` and still see the same behavior. That's because `not myVar` needs to be evaluated. And before the bits can be flipped, `Empty` will have to be converted to its Long representation first. Apparently, after the execution of the statement it stays Long. This might be considered a bug.

Comment: And if you read [Eric Lippert's article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2003/09/15/52996.aspx) on the use of parentheses, it will also make sense why using `MsgBox Not (myVar)` instead of `MsgBox Not myVar` will not cause a change in BEFORE/AFTER. Using parentheses causes the parameter to be passed by value. That means the Not operator works on a _copy_ of `myVar` so the original `myVar` is left untouched.

Comment: Well done for being the first to use the word "bug" here, which is what I believe this to be! Or at least, an un-documented _feature_ :). I did consider the byval implications of parentheses, but as the statement is not a function call I'm not sure if that applies?

Comment: @beercohol I agree with you. a bug or an un-documented behavior. have a look at my records for `Visual Basic for Application` : http://i.imgur.com/exNuoCK.gif `Visual Basic 6` : http://i.imgur.com/vtNqm1t.gif and finally the buggy `VBScript` : http://i.imgur.com/NbbZy5P.gif BTW the difference between `myVar` and `(myVar)` is not interesting, see another doc (4th paragraph) : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee478101%28v=vs.84%29.aspx (... T*he argument is passed by value if it is enclosed in parentheses* ...) .  another option is using CBool (e.g. `If Not CBool(myVar) Then ...`)

Comment: Thanks that is the best answer I've had so far - if you can write it as a full answer that would be really useful! Seeing the VBA, VB6 an VBS results all together just reinforces my opinion that this is indeed a bug in the VBS interpreter.

Comment: @beercohol Done! I've never encountered this problem before. Thanks to you I've learned something new.

Comment: Yes I was thinking that too after reading the article you linked to, and some of Eric's other blog posts too. It would be awesome if he or any others who've worked first hand on MS's language tools could comment!

Comment: At the risk of appearing as a bad loser I'd like to get something off my chest. What @Kul-tigin shows (nicely illustrated!) is that the same behavior is not shown in VBA nor in (the non-scripting language that happens to share syntax) VB6. You already stated that ASP _does_ behave the same. All I see is some support to our suspicion that this might indeed be a bug. What I don't see in Kul-tigin's answer, but what you are specifically asking for in your original post, is an _explanation_.

Comment: The lack of an explanation in Kul-Tigin's answer is a fair comment, but that's also true of all the answers so far including yours, which did raise a couple of interesting points as I commented already. If it _is_ a bug (in a very old product) then a definitive answer is probably only going to be possible in the unlikely event of @EricLippert or someone else from MS answering. Failing an authoritative source, I'm willing to consider an empirical answer that demonstrates the scope of the issue across various platforms, which Kul-Tigin's makes a good stab at.

Comment: Following on from that, I'd be really interested to see the results from other VB/VBS/VBA interpreters, like chilisoft ASP for example. I might try a few further tests myself...

Comment: But I _did_ give you an explanation. Executing `x = Not myVar` returns a value in x that has the bits of `myVar` flipped (according to VBscript reference documentation). Since you can not perform a bitwise operation on an abstraction like `Empty` it will have to be converted to its integer representation. This is 0 as `CLng(myVar)` shows. The value of `x` will be -1 which is the bitwise complement of 0. Since myVar was passed to `Not` by-reference the value of myVar stays 0 afterwards.

Answer (score 4):

https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee198865.aspx

So, if you create a variable without initializing it, the variable will take on one of these default values:
If you use the variable as a string, the initial value will be Empty.
If you use the variable as a number, the initial value will be 0.

I would think that since you are doing a Boolean check, you are essentially using myVar as a number, and your statement is read like:

```
if not 0 then myVar2 = true
'same as: if not FALSE then myVar2 = true
```

And so myVar is initialized to 0

Comment: Interesting link thanks, but it only talks about the variables being coerced to default values of empty string or zero in expressions where they are used, nothing about actual _assignment_ of a value.
In the X & Y examples on that page the variables always remain empty as one would expect.

Comment: @beercohol - actually it does talk about assignment (smack in the middle of the page): "*Numeric variables that have not been initialized are automatically **assigned** the value 0*"

Comment: Sure it does say that, but it's pretty clear that it actually means "assigned" in the context of the **expression** where the empty var is **used**. The use of the term "assigned" is pretty loose I think, and it doesn't say anything about **storing** any value into the variable **in a non-assignment statement.**

Answer (score 3):

These are the rules from VBA https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177324.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

The point is that variables (though not objects) always have a usuable value (objects do have a value of nothing).

> **5.5.1.2.2 Let-coercion to and from Boolean**
>
> When not stored as a Boolean value, False is represented by 0, and True is represented by nonzero values, usually -1.
>
> The semantics of Boolean Let-coercion depend on the source’s value type and the destination’s declared type:

```
Source Value Type Destination Declared Type Semantics
Boolean     Boolean     The result is a copy of the source value.
Boolean     Any numeric type except Byte     If the source value is False, the result is 0. Otherwise, the result is -1.
Boolean     Byte     If the source value is False, the result is 0. Otherwise, the result is 255.
Any numeric type     Boolean     If the source value is 0, the result is False. Otherwise, the result is True
```

> **5.5.1.2.11 Let-coercion from Empty**
>
> The semantics of Empty Let-coercion depend on the destination’s declared type:

```
Source Value Type Destination Declared Type Semantics
Empty Any numeric type The result is 0.
Empty Boolean The result is False.
Empty Date The result is 12/30/1899 00:00:00.
Empty String The result is a 0-length string.
Empty String * length The result is a string containing length spaces.
Empty Any class or Object Runtime error 424 (Object required) is raised.
Empty Any other type except Variant Runtime error 13 (Type mismatch) is raised.
```

Your variable is coerced as a string when you first messagebox it.

Then it is coerced as false in line above.

> 5.6.9.5 Relational Operators
>   Relational operators are simple data operators that perform comparisons between their operands.

```
relational-operator = equality-operator / inequality-operator / less-than-operator / greaterthan-operator / less-than-equal-operator / greater-than-equal-operator
```

Static semantics:

> Relational operators are statically resolved as simple data operators.
>
> A relational operator is invalid if the declared type of any operand is an array or UDT.
>
> A relational operator has the following declared type, based on the declared type of its operands:

```
Left Operand Declared Type Right Operand Declared Type Operator Declared Type
Any type except an array, UDT or Variant Any type except an array, UDT or Variant Boolean Any type except an array or UDT Variant 
 Variant Any type except an array or UDT Variant
```

> **Runtime semantics**:
>
> Relational operators are first evaluated as simple data operators.
>
> If the value type of any operand is an array or UDT, runtime error 13 (Type mismatch) is raised.
>
> Before evaluating the relational operator, its non-Null operands undergo Let-coercion to the operator’s effective value type.
>
> The effective value type is determined as follows, based on the value types of the operands:
>
> **5.6.9.5.1 = Operator**
>
> The = operator performs a value equality comparison on its operands.
>       equality-operator = expression "=" expression
>
> **Runtime semantics:**
>
> If the operands are considered equal, True is returned. Otherwise, False is returned.

Comment: Thanks, but I haven't tried this in VBA. Also, I can't see any of what you reference above in the link provided.
In any case I don't believe the msgbox has any relevance here, it's simply my way of showing output in a VBS. I guess you're saying that you believe my variable is coerced where it is concatenated into the "msg" var for output. Indeed I'm sure it is coerced (to a default empty string) when that _expression_ is evaluated, but that's not the same as making a permanent assignment. If it were so the first "isempty" would also show false.

Comment: No I'm saying it's coerced, maybe, in the expression evaluation. It is not changed for msgbox, because it's a function - maybe.

Comment: I don't think that can be the case, else my first calls to "isempty" and "typename" would return non-empty values.
The change definitely seems to be occurring on the "if not myVar then myVar2 = true" statment.

Comment: Isempty and typename are function calls.